# SQL Server Filtering Unique Latest Date and Pay

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my example, there are more than one of the same EMPID depending on how many PAY's is associated to to that variable.  However, for each PAY and EMPID, there is only 1 DATE.  What I am trying to show is the latest PAY for each EMPID.  This is turn would leave only distinct EMPID's in the results.  The following code is what I have so far, and it is not working out so great for me.

It has been resulting in an error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Any help on this would be great.

```
SELECT
    [EMPID],
    MAX([DATE]) AS 'last_date',
    [PAY] 
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY [EMPID]
HAVING
    (SELECT [PAY] 
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE [DATE] = MAX([DATE])
    GROUP BY [EMPID])
GO
```

Comment: Your Having clause is wrong. Your subquery must returns a boolean of a value. But if pay is a value it must be compare with something (i.e. > 0 ??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer about your error:

Your Having clause is wrong. Your subquery must returns a boolean of a value. But if pay is a value it must be compare with something (i.e. > 0 ??)

But you can rewrite your query as follow:

You'll get only row with max date (expressed as follow: doesn't exist another row with the same `VARIABLE1` with a next date)

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'NEXT'
    FROM table1 t2
    WHERE t2.variable1 = t1.variable1
    AND t2.date > t1.date
)
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to do:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM TABLE1 e
WHERE e.[DATE] = (SELECT MAX(e2.[DATE])
                  FROM TABLE1 e2
                  WHERE e2.EMPID = e.EMPID
                 );
```

This seems closest to what you are attempting.  The performance should be good with an index on `(EMPID, DATE)`, and the intention of the query is quite clear.

Perhaps a more common way to write the query is to use `row_number()` or `rank()`:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT e.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPID ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) as seqnum
      FROM TABLE1 e
     ) e
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This version guarantees only one row per `EMPID`, even if an `EMPID` has multiple rows for the same maximum date.  `rank()` would get all rows, as your query would.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this:

```
SELECT 
    t.*
FROM
    [Table] t
INNER JOIN
     (
         SELECT 
             MAX([Date])
             [VARIABLE1]
         FROM 
              [TABLE]
         GROUP BY
               [VARIABLE1]
       ) t2
ON
    t2.[VARIABLE1] = t.[VARIABLE1] AND
    t.[DATE] = t2.[DATE];
```

Comment: Rather `TOP 1` as the OP uses SQL Server.

Comment: `TOP 1` is better. I changed it around, I think he wants it for each value of `[VARIABLE1]`